# How to not showing the drawer, when the user press the back button on the pushed widget

Tags: flutter

Using a Drawer and then push when ListTile onTab:

```
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                new MyWidget();
```

Is it possible to have a navigation not showing the drawer when the user press the back button on the pushed widget - and just show the Scaffold body?

I looked at wrapping MyWidget in `WillPopScope` and then callback, but no success?

I only want to show the Drawer when the user clicks the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to close the drawer before going to the next screen. You can do this by using `Navigator.pop(context);` before you call your second screen.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
         padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text("Title page"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```